# concatenate values across two rows in R

Tags: r, concatenation, paste

I am trying to concatenate two rows from a data frame in R with a similar format

```
row1 <- c("A","B","C")
row2 <- c(1:3)
dat <- data.frame(rbind(row1,row2))
dat
     X1 X2 X3
row1  A  B  C
row2  1  2  3
```

I would like third row of the type

```
row3 A-1 B-2 C-3
```

Can someone help me to do this using the paste function? I have been trying the following without success:

```
> paste(dat[1,], dat[2,], sep="-")
[1] "2-1" "2-1" "2-1"
> paste(as.character(dat[1,]), dat[2,], sep="-")
[1] "2-1" "2-1" "2-1"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do a `dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.character)` first, and then try your first approach.

Comment: thanks, this works great! I appreciate it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
rbind(dat, row3 = apply(dat, 2, paste0, collapse = "-"))
#      X1  X2  X3
#row1   A   B   C
#row2   1   2   3
#row3 A-1 B-2 C-3
```

Provided that you have taken the necessary steps to avoid using `factor`s, i.e.

```
row1 <- c("A","B","C")
row2 <- as.character(1:3)
dat <- data.frame(
  rbind(row1, row2), 
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(dat, setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse='-')]))
#    X1  X2  X3
#1:   A   B   C
#2:   1   2   3
#3: A-1 B-2 C-3
```

Comment: I like this solution, how can I adjust this, when I want to concatenate multiple rows grouped by ID? So basically I want to achieve the following at once:
 My input should be: 
input <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,3,3,3),
                   X1 = c("A", 1, 11, "D", 4, 44),
                   X2 = c("B", 2, 22, "E", 5, 55),
                   X3 = c("C", 3, 33, "F", 6, 66))

And my output should be:
output <- data.frame(ID = c(1,3),
                     X1 = c("A-1-11", "D-4-44"),
                     X2 = c("B-2-22", "E-5-55"),
                     X3 = c("C-3-33", "F-6-66"))

Comment: @KidLu `setDT(input)[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse='-'), by = ID]`